# Stuck with this programming question for school

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

I'm writing a simple Java program for school. I can't seem to understand why I am getting `Error: Cannot Find Symbol` .

Here's the whole code with the error at the bottom.

[image: code + error]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: `RAD` is a parameter that is passed to a method and then that value is stored in the field `radius` - You should use `radius` in your getter method

Comment: Also, please do not post code as images, show the relevant code as text in your question

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the concept of [scope](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope).  Just because you've defined a variable (e.g. RAD) one place in your program, doesn't mean it's available in other places (like "getRadius()").

For example:

```
public class Circle extends Shape {

  private double radius;
  ...
  public double getRadius() { return radius; }
  ...
```

This works because I've defined "radius" as a [member variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).  "radius" is visible anywhere in this class object - and not available at all outside of it.

Which is one example of [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 0):

In your method getRadius(), you're returning variable RAD that isn't defined in the local method, as a parameter, and it's not a class variable, so RAD is unknown in that method.

Instead of "return RAD" I think you want to "return radius" which is the class variable.

Answer (score 0):

RAD is not declared in the scope of the Method getRadius. Instead of RAD, you should return radius. Another observation in your code, circle() is defined as a method whereas it should be a constructor.